# Using BETWEEN in SQL CASE where clause

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I Have a form, where the user pulls a report.
In the form they can choose a start date and an end date, or pass through a null for both values. If they choose null, it returns all records where effectivedate < GETDATE()
The CASE statement doesn't seem to like between, nor does it like '<' operators

Here is my script

```
SELECT * FROM tbReport
WHERE 
    EffectiveDate 
    CASE 
        WHEN (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL) 
        THEN BETWEEN (@StartDate AND @EndDate)          
         ELSE 
                  THEN < GETDATE()

    END
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could rewrite it without a case, like:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM   tbReport
WHERE   (
            @StartDate is not null 
            and 
            @EndDate is not null
            and 
            EffectiveDate between @StartDate AND @EndDate
        )
        or
        (
            (
                @StartDate is null 
                or 
                @EndDate is null
            )
            and 
            EffectiveDate < getdate()
        )
```

Comment: Thanks this answer makes the most sense to me and takes into account all the conditions.

Comment: It works but is it not a bit complicated for what is required?  It wouldn't be my first choice from a maintainability standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is SQL Server, you can simplify this by using isnull:

```
select *
from tbReport
where EffectiveDate between isnull(@StartDate, '1 Jan 1990')
      and isnull(@EndDate, getdate())
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't take into account that if either of the dates are null, return all records where effectivedate < GETDATE()

Comment: Yea if you take out the BETWEEN and use AND instead you handle when either params are null.  Look at my answer to see what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work,  I havent checked the syntax is correct though.

```
SELECT * FROM tbReport
WHERE EffectiveDate < IsNull(@EndDate,GetDate())
AND EffectiveDate > IsNull(@StartDate,'01/01/1979')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for CASE is all wrong here.. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM tbReport
WHERE 
    (@StartDate is null and @EndDate is null and EffectiveDate < GetDate()) or 
    (@StartDate is not null and @EndDate is not null and 
     EffectiveDate >= @StartDate and EffectiveDate <= @EndDate)
```

Comment: While this is a very good select .. you should put an or between first @startdate and @enddate (@StartDate is null or @EndDate is null) and EffectiveDate < GetDate(), otherwise you will miss records.

Answer (score 0):

the SQL statement is not written correct. Case will not conditionally chose the evaluated code. You can look to the case as a value, so you have to put an operator between the case and the other operand.

One of the multiple ways of writing this would be:

```
where 
case when @StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL and EffectiveDate BETWEEN (@StartDate AND @EndDate)   then 1
case when (@StartDate IS NULL OR @EndDate IS NULL) and EffectiveDate <getdate() then 1
else 0 end = 1
```

If you do not want to write it with case you can chose one of the solutions before, but they use a discrete starting date.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 

(SR.RecCreateTS BETWEEN  ( CASE WHEN  @SubmittedBegining IS NOT NULL  THEN @SubmittedBegining ELSE SR.RecCreateTS END )
                            AND ( CASE WHEN  @SubmittedEnding IS NOT NULL   THEN @SubmittedEnding ELSE SR.RecCreateTS END )
                            )
```

Comment: Hello! Please format your code (use Ctrl+K) and edit your answer to describe how this solves the question.